# Arch / KDE - desktop resolution reverts to default after a quick "blink" on requested resolution

Tags: arch-linux, kde

I'm experiencing the behaviour in KDE on Arch that when I change monitor resolution, the requested resolution is briefly rendered before quickly returning to the default resolution.

The selected resolutions are valid for the monitor, and are validly rendered briefly but only remain set for a moment before the previous resolution of 800 x 600 is reapplied.

I've tried following a few guides including https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Screen_resolution_reverts_back_after_a_blink and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238561 but they don't seem completely applicable to my situation: I'm not running gnome, and I can't find a ~/.config/monitors.xml file

A few outputs that might be relevant:

[xrandr -q](https://pastebin.com/whkx1rU6)
[xorg.log](https://pastebin.com/n0HLHcpm)
[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/AAYx89Ep)

Comment: I am having the same problem. For me the issue is only with KDE. I installed Gnome, XFCE, and Deepin alongside KDE and the only one that is affected is KDE.

I'm on KDE 5.16.2 running with KVM.

Reading through the ArchWiki I found that your local configuration settings for kscreen (~/.local/share/kscreen/) can override those set in xorg.conf. Changing and/or removing that file did nothing for me though.

Comment: @etho201a little strange: there was one file in that folder with settings of the mointor. I changed the resolutions from 800x600 to 1600x1200. When I logged in again the monitor was displaying in 1440x900 and there was a new file in the folder...